# The right way to remove attribute from rails model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

There is phone attribute in customer model with our rails 3.2.12 app. We would like to remove the phone attribute sometime when retrieving customers. Here is what we did:

```
@customers = Customer.all
@customers.delete :phone
```

However there is error:

```
delete_all doesn't support limit scope
```

What's the right way to remove an attribute from a model object? Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to just not display the phone number, rather than delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Customer.select('name, address')` to retrieve only the fields you want.  Noting that you pass a string with comma separated field named.

This will generate an SQL request like this

```
SELECT customer.name, customer.address FROM customer
```

You then get only the data you want without deleting it from the database (which is what your original call is trying to do).

My original response showed incorrect use of pluck, which only works for a single column.

Comment: Very interesting! The pluck definition (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) says it returns an array with values of the specified single column name. Can we retrieve multiple columns? Also can we apply further SQL operation (like .where) on the object returned by pluck?

Comment: Just tested in rails console, pluck can only take one column.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are using Rails 3.2.12, but in Rails 4 pluck also [works with multiple columns](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck), allowing something like

```
Customer.pluck(:name, :address)
```